# Is there an R function for performing basic operations on every column of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with n columns like the one below with all the columns being numeric (ex. below only has 3, but the actual one has an unknown number).

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 
1      3     7   
3      8     9   
5      5     2 
8      10    1
11     9     2
```

I'm trying to transform the data on every column based on this equation: `(x-min(col)/(max(col)-min(col))` so that every element is scaled based on the values in the column.

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop to iterate through every column? Would sapply or tapply work here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `scale` on the dataset

```
scale(df1)
```

Or if we want to use a custom function, create the function, loop over the columns with `lapply`, apply the function and assign it back to the dataframe

```
f1 <- function(x) (x-min(col)/(max(col)-min(col))
df1[] <- lapply(df1, f1)
```

---

Or this can be done with `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>%
    mutate_all(f1)
```

Comment: For the sake of completness, you could also propose the `data.table` option: `df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) return((x-min(col)/(max(col)-min(col)))]`

Comment: Ok that's nice !

Answer (score 5):

In complement to @akrun answer, you can also do that using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) return((x-min(col)/(max(col)-min(col)))]
```

If you want to use a subset of columns, you can use `.SDcols` argument, e.g.

```r
library(data.table)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) return((x-min(col)/(max(col)-min(col))),
.SDcols = c('a','b')]
```